# reordering 3D vector triplets in column major order is slow

Tags: c++, c, sse, simd

I'm having a lots of (x1,y1,z1),(x2,y2,z2),(x3,y3,z3)  single precision vector triplets, and I want to reorder them, so
(x1,y1,z1),(x2,y2,z2),(x3,y3,z3) 
becomes
(x1,x2,x3,0,y1,y2,y3,0,z1,z2,z3,0)

The goal is to prepere the dataset for an SSE based calculation. I have the following code to do this:

```
for (int i=0;i<count;i++)
{
    Vect3F p0 = get_first_point(i);
    Vect3F p1 = get_second_point(i);
    Vect3F p2 = get_third_point(i);
    int idx = i*3;
    scratch[idx] = Vec4F(p0.x, p1.x, p2.x, 0); // These 3 rows are the slowest
    scratch[idx+1] = Vec4F(p0.y, p1.y, p2.y, 0);
    scratch[idx+2] = Vec4F(p0.z, p1.z, p2.z, 0);
}
```

The last 3 rows of the loop are extremely slow, they take 90% percent of the time of my entire algorithm!

Is it normal? Can I make such shuffleing faster?
(*scratch* is a static variable, and is 16-aligned. The function is called frequently, so I think the blocks of *scratch* should not disappear from the cache.)

Comment: There seem to be a lot of temporary objects being created here. Hopefully, the compiler is eliding the constructors, assignments, etc. Have you considered implementing the Vect3F, Vect4F members as a union with an aligned SSE (__m128) type?

Comment: Unfortunatly Vect3F could not be aligned, it should be 12 byte long, so I can't make any use of SSE when I'm reordering floats. When it's done, I'm using _mm_load_ps to load data into registers (and it's fast). Now I expanded all my constructors, and assignments:
`float* a = (float*)(cache + i*3);
a[0] = p0.x; a[1] = p1.x; a[2] = p2.x;
a[4] = p0.y; a[5] = p1.y; a[6] = p2.y;
a[8] = p0.z; a[9] = p1.z; a[10] = p2.z;`
Helped a bit, but it's still very slow.

Comment: Does this snippet even compile? You declare Vect3F p0 three times!

Comment: Here is how the original code look's like (I changed it in editor later, to make it look simplier): `int tri = triangles[i];Vect3F p0 = points[indices[tri]];  Vect3F p1 = points[indices[tri+1]];Vect3F p2 = points[indices[tri+2]];`

Comment: This is essentially matrix transposing. Google sse transpose and you'll get some faster versions.

Comment: Even if the compiler optimizes the p0, p1, p2 temp object access, it would be better to use: **const Vect3F & p0 = points[i];**

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you shouln't create 3 temporary vector objects.
Instead of:

```
tri = triangles[i];
Vect3F p0 = points[indices[tri]];
Vect3F p1 = points[indices[tri+1]];
Vect3F p2 = points[indices[tri+2]];
```

You should just copy data using memcpy(); Make a loop that goes for your entire collection and copies raw data. It is the fastest way I can think of.

Using 3 variables runs a lot of constructors which are painfully slow. The second way (from comment) isn't much better for the same reason.

Comment: Makes me wonder what compilers you are using and what flags. I think the code should be somewhat rendered the same with proper optimizations turned on.